# For loop not iterating while trying to combine files in a directory

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to slice the .lvm files at row 22 and convert them into csv files, I have around 50 .lvm files in my directory. So after each of them are cropped I need them to be merged together in the csv file.

But I am not able to iterate between my .lvm files.

```
path = "/mnt/b818255b-46bc-4a89-9ef3-42138e2ad25f/PASST 4.0/Messdaten/*.lvm"
for fname in glob.glob(path):
    with open(fname, 'rb') as fin:
        reader = csv.reader(fin)


        for row in reader:
            for field in row:
                     with open(fname) as f, open("out.csv","a") as out:
                        r = csv.reader(islice(f,22,None))
                        wr = csv.writer(out)
                        wr.writerows(r)
```

But the first file in the directory is always taken inside the for loop. Can anyone please help me understand the problem?

Comment: Why are you opening the file twice?

Comment: What do you mean by "The first file in the directory is always taken inside the for loop"? Do you have a lvm file that should not match your expression that you still open?

Comment: i removed it and it worked thanks @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams

Comment: @Metareven I meant 1 st file out of 50 files was only going inside the loop.

Comment: i just removed 'with open(fname) as f' and replaced f with fin. it was my mistake opening the same file twice